# Antonym for 'bound'

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of the term **London-bound** (meaning heading/travelling to London) - i.e. moving away from London?

Comment: ah, London-leaving?

Comment: London outbound? By the way, language is not subject to Newton's second law of motion, namely that for every action there must be an equal and opposite reaction. Not all words necessarily have antonyms.

Comment: I'm most familiar with "departing from" as it's often used at airports.

Comment: Bear in mind Dr Samuel Johnson's remark *When a man is tired of London, he is tired of life*. Perhaps best to stay *London-bound*.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Was just interested in what people thought about this. Cheers.

Comment: It depends on where the vehicle is heading. If the train's destination is Bristol, then the opposite of _London-bound_ is _Bristol-bound_ ;^)

Comment: London-originating, perhaps.

Comment: ... from London

Answer (score 1):

**"outbound from London"**

> *outbound*
>
> ADJECTIVE & ADVERB
>
> Travelling away from a particular place, especially on the first leg of a return journey:
>
> [AS ADJECTIVE]: an outbound flight
>   [AS ADVERB]: flying outbound
>
> - *I was now, however, on familiar territory having travelled along these forest roads on my outbound journey.*
> - *We took a different flightpath to my outbound journey; the landscape was much more urban, but still noticeably Dutch.*
> - *The outbound date of travel determines the fare for the entire journey and ticketing must be within seven days of booking.*

[outbound. Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press, n.d. Web. 27 January 2015.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/outbound)

> *outbound*, adj. and adv.
>
> A. adj. 
>   1. Outward-bound.
>   2. Relating to (arrangements for) travel outwards, or to people or vehicles travelling outwards.
>
> B. adv. 
>   While travelling away from home; when moving outside or outwards.

["outbound, adj. and adv." OED Online. Oxford University Press, December 2014. Web. 27 January 2015.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/133445)

> *Cathay Pacific flights **outbound from Heathrow** have been making a fuel stop, when necessary, at Amsterdam, Singapore Airlines at Frankfurt, and Qantas at Stansted.*

[Heathrow fuel problems to last 'months'](http://www.uk-airport-news.info/heathrow-airport-news-191205c.htm)

Answer (score 0):

"Departed" is used most often in transportation contexts, or making the vehicle owned by the place departed: "The next train at Hogsmeade is the London Hogwarts Express."

Answer (score 0):

If in both cases the speaker is not located in London, I would describe the train coming from London as "inbound from London".